# What's the meaning of potential energy in quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, definition

We know that the definition of potential energy in classic physics. When we start learning about quantum physics and especially the Schrodinger equation we blindly accept the potential energy part. I would like to know what's the meaning of potential energy when it comes to quantum physics.

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for here? It has more or less the same meaning that it has in classical mechanics.

Comment: It means "existing interaction", just like in CM.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum mechanics is based on Hamiltonian mechanics or if you want, analytical mechanics in general. That means it utilizes the same concepts of kinetic energy and potential energy among others that you may have encountered already in Newtonian mechanics. Their meaning is exactly the same in classical and quantum mechanics, since quantization does not modify these definitions.

That is quantum mechanics addresses the commutation of certain conjugate variables, such as position and momentum but leaves the definition of potential energy intact. Specifically, the potential captures the interactions from the environment (including possibly other particles) where a particle/body is "moving". In perhaps traditional terms it represents energy stored via working against some force, may it be a Coulomb force, or gravitational or whatever effective force you might encounter.